# Forcing long layer names to multiple lines based on specified legend width in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, legend

Do to various limitations I almost always create static (graphic) legends but I do have the occasional map where impeccable cartography is secondary to functionality hence a dynamic legend is acceptable.

I am Currently working on a map where I want the legend to be 4" wide with one legend column.  I need to show very long layer names in the legend but **I don't know how to force labels to roll to multiple lines dynamically.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you use Descriptions?  They can handle multiple lines in the legend.
[image]

Comment: Descriptions are the way I do it too

Comment: Use ctrl + enter for line breaks in descriptions