# Allowing for multiple lines in legend of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend

How can I force the description text in my legend to occupy more than one line?

This is basically the same question as [Forcing long layer names to multiple lines based on specified legend width in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/legend-can-i-force-long-layer-names-to-multiple-lines-based-on-a-specified-lege).

However, I want to use *Categories/Unique values* and not *Features* as my Symbology style, in which case there's no Description button. Even when I change to *Features*, it seems I can't use multiple lines (I suppose that there's been some changes to this functionality).

How would I go about getting the description/header text across multiple lines?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In 10.1 you have a lot more control over legends. You should be able to wrap both the labels and the description using the Text Wrapping option in the Layout tab (see below)

[image]

If that still doesn't work you can manually force the line breaks using the Symbology tab in the Layer Properties. If you right click each of your unique values and select Edit Description you can enter text (See the next image)

[image]

Once in the edit description you can put in line breaks by hitting CONTROL ENTER to get a new line.

Also check this out for more info: [Arc 10.1 Legend Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Working_with_legends/00s900000023000000/)

That should give you enough options to get the legend the way you want it.