# Long description layer in legend of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, mxd, arcgis-10.3

I work with arcview 10.3 and i have layer with long description (green),hence the legend spread throw out the map:
[image]

I have to use a singel symbol for the layer
[image]

and not use the unique value as describe in 
[How to allow for multiple lines in legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/how-to-allow-for-multiple-lines-in-legend)
[image]

I wonder if there a way to shorten the description line by sliding the line into another line under ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click

> CTRL+ Enter

a new line is entered and reflected within the legend.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this from the Help page entitled [Working with legends](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-legends.htm) where it says:

> You can enable **text wrapping** on labels and **descriptions** by checking
>   the boxes Wrap labels and **Wrap descriptions**, respectively, and setting
>   maximum width values.

If there are any issues doing that, then the section on Converting map elements to graphics at the same page says:

> You might want to convert a map element, such as a legend, to graphics
>   if you want more precise control over each item that composes the map
>   element.

Fortunately, the first technique above seems to work fine because I did as below and saw the Description of a layer with a Single Symbol wrapped as expected.

[image]

[image]

[image]